# Handle nonce after RPC timeout

Tags: rpc, nonce

From time to time, I will be making some 5 ~ 10 tx/s on Ethereum via RPC interface.

I have to handle the nonce manually because it cannot update fast enough. But I am facing issue below:

1. From time to time to RPC will fail, and I will have to reset the nonce.
2. Some times the RPC will fail and timeout, but the tx was processed successfully eventually. I can't reset the nonce in this case. Because if I reset, it will not be accurate anymore

In short, I don't know what shall I do when there is an error with the RPC. I don't know what to do with the nonce and don't know how to send the next transaction.

Comment: Save last nonce somewhere?

Comment: Not possible, since I do not know if the previous transaction was failed / successful

Comment: If transaction is confirmed, it is successful, nothing impossible here.

Comment: I do not know if it is committed or not, because the RPC was timeout, and I am not able to get back the Transaction receipt. I have no idea whether it is succeed or failed.

Comment: RPC has a feature, every request goes with unique `id`, every response returns that `id`, save that `id` and check whenever response good or not, nothing hard, it is simple programming task.